# How do I make a reusable UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

So I want to make a UIView that have a image and two text labels inside, but I want to make it on storyboard and make it reusable, because they will appear in another situations.

What is the best way to make a non-intrusive custom UIView?

Comment: When dont you make a segue to that view when it is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for storyboard you will still need to use a .xib. I use storyboard but have found no other way just to make a custom UIView.

- Create a new view in xCode and delete the view controller.
- Draw a UIView over into the workspace
- Setup the identifier and tie it to your UIView class.
- Add your text boxes and what not.
- Save your newly created .xib
- Call in your custom view into your code

Here is a bit more detail with step by step process. http://nathanhjones.com/2011/02/20/creating-reusable-uiviews-with-a-drop-shadow-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks a lot Bot! YOu nailed it!